# Can you update QPython3 version of Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, version, qpython, qpython3

I want to install biopython on Qpython3 but it says that I have python 3.2 and need version 3.3 or greater. Is there no version of QPython3 available with a higher version? Can I update it somehow?
-Thanks

Comment: Getting `numpy` and compiling the C code might be a greater barrier than the Python version.

Comment: Yes I soon realised this after posting it. I would have to use a cross compiler and pre build the stuff before I install it manually, pretty lame. QPython should start a database full of stuff that's precompiled for phones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's something in the wiki about changing the core

http://wiki.qpython.org/zh/diveinto/#how-to-replace-the-python-core

but it is rather short and cryptic, ending with

> More detail coming soon ...

Comment: You're right, it is cryptic, if anyone else has info that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Now, you can install qpy36 (http://qpy36.qpython.org/) to update QPython3's core.