# QPython unicode string

Tags: xlwt, unicode-string, qpython, qpython3

In QPython3, a line like `s = u"Hello"` raises a syntax error for some reason.

I want to install a module that uses such code (namely `xlwt`) and therefore `pip install xlwt` fails.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866148/qpython-unicode-strings) is very similar but the workaround does not work since the problem is in 3rd party code.

Weirdly, the install works perfectly fine with QPython2. But I wrote all my code with Python3 features.

Does anyone know how I could get a line unicode strings to work in QPython3 ?

**EDIT**

I just realised QPython3 is running Python3.2 where the unicode raw strings were still banned and restored with Python3.3.

I am still looking for a workaround or a Python3.3+ interpreter for Android.

If you have an idea, I put a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875258/can-you-update-qpython3-version-of-python3).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct about this, "" is a byte string in Python 2, u"" is a Unicode string in Python 2, b"" is a byte string in Python 3, "" is a Unicode string in Python 3.

Is this the answer you want? Or I misunderstood the meaning of the question?